# in Bash, search file for a string and append file with string if it is not existing

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I need to find a better way to handle this situation.  This is what i am doing, and what i would like to do:

I am taking data from a program that loops all day.  I want to add all new data to append a file (file1).
The program in a loop sends repeat data 1000's of times per day or more.  I only want to add lines that do not exist already in my file1.
Rather than to write the data for file1, use awk to trim off the duplicates, write to file2, delete file1, copy the file2 to files1's path, and delete file2, i'd like to know if there is a way to keep just one file in existence the entire time?  I am using SD memory and i feel like after a few days i will have burned through my SD cards life.  I need to make use of the RAM or some other command that can read a file's text, edit it, and save it back to itself.
This is the code that gets teh job done, but i feel it is very hard on my SD Card:

```
echo $datafromprogram >> file1
awk '!seen[$0]++' file1 >> file2
rm file1
cp file2 file1
rm file2
```

I have also tried using some logic to check the file1 if $datafromprogram already exists, but for some reason this works when i do the sample code, but when i replace `echo not found` with `echo $datafromprogram >> file1` , every time i run the code it always ends up using the "else", even if the strings match perfectly.

Sample Code:

```
if grep -q PATTERN file.txt; then
    echo found
else
    echo not found
fi
```

My Code:

```
if grep -Fxq $datafromprogram file1; then
echo "String already exists"
else
echo $datafromprogram >> file1
fi
```

Comment: double-quote your variables to avoid word-splitting by shell i.e. have it as `"$datafromprogram"`

Comment: Thanks but no thanks.  I dont think you even read my question.  Im not having a word splitting issue.  I am trying to avoid using 2 files.  id like to automate the modification of one text file without saving new file, deleting original, renaming other file to original file's name.  Please re-read the question and be sure of what is being asked before you answer something that is not being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution to fit my requirements best.

```
grep -E "$datafromprogram" file1 || echo "$datafromprogram" >> file1
```

All this is doing is using grep to check file1 for the string.  Double-piping will return either a true or false.  If it returns false, it appends file1 with the string.

Sorry but i forgot where i found this idea.  If i can find the link in my history at home later, i will add it to this answer.